# Facebook doesnt accept Domain rsb-gerlach.de

Tags: facebook

anyone knows why facebook does not accept the domain rsb-gerlach.de for website or email in page settings for a travel agency facebook page?

Neither https://www.rsb-gerlach.de nor mail@rsb-gerlach.de works. I cant see any DNS conflicts or something why it should not work.

Chris

Comment: Facebook has blocked the domain for not following their “community standards” in the past, as you can see from https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/?q=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.rsb-gerlach.de%2F

Comment: okay, seems to be very hard to get a blacklisted unblocked, but thanks anyway.